# Problem in running website project

Tags: asp.net

When a run my website project then it gives me error of `'Unable to connect to asp development server'`. I am using Visual Studio 2010. Only my website projects are having these prblems. 
I have tried reinstalling vs2010  . But again & again i m having same problem.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance & Happy New Year 2011. I wish this will bring a lot of happiness and prosperity in everyone's life.

Comment: Do you have any database server installed e.g. Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **if there is any server install in your system ,then stop there services,
>   and restart visual  studio again and start web services of IIS**

Comment: Thanks buddy, u have solved my problem. u made my day. thanks